# Why can't the user enter another value after an a single iteration?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that lets the user enter a number and that number will be the length of some array. After that I want to tell the user to enter values to go into that array. However I am having some trouble trying to figure out why my for loop is not working as intended. It runs once then the program ends.

Here is my code:

```
public class PutNumbersIntoArray {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int n = args[0].length();

        int[] arr = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a number to go into your array: ");
            arr[i] = StdIn.readInt();
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `the user enter a number and that number will be the length of some array` I guess you are using the incorrect way. With `args[0].length();` you are getting the length of the string, in this case if it is "5" the length for that string is 1.

Comment: To can get the number you sent, you will have to parse the string: `int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0])`

Comment: ``args[0].length`` should cause a compiler error or be equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Print out n and see what is in that value before your loop starts.  You haven't included the code where that is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = Integer.decode(args[0]);
BufferedReader stdIn =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int[] arr = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a number to go into your array: ");
    arr[i] = Integer.decode(stdIn.readLine());
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Try to use java.io.Console for user inputs.

Comment: You should use Integer.parseInt() rather than Integer.decode() to get the int value of a string. Integer.decode() returns an Integer rather than an int.

Comment: Due to auto unboxing there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Yes, but if you use Integer.parseInt(), you get an actual int without the need for unboxing. I realize that an Integer will get you the right answer eventually, but the result is that an int is converted to an Integer, which is then converted to an int again.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use such code:    

    Scanner  StdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a length of our array: ");
    int n = StdIn.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number " + i + " into your array: ");
        arr[i] = StdIn.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Your array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i]+ " ");
    }
}
```